# Bold x axis values in jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart

How can I **bold** the x and y axis values in jfreechart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried one of those:

```
yourAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10)); //to define a specific font
```

or

```
Font bold = yourAxis.getTickLabelFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
yourAxis.setTickLabelFont(bold); //to use the existing font, but bold
```